# If I install Steam games on my second drive, do I need the folder that was created on the main drive?

Tags: steam

If I install Steam games on my second drive, do I need the folder that was created on the main drive?

For example, while I was searching for gigabyte-sized files to clean up my C drive, I found huge Cyberpunk 2077 files in the "Program Files (x86)" directory, despite the fact that I install my games on my second one and they're not even installed at the moment. If not the whole folder, are there any that are safe to delete?

Comment: Where exactly in your C drive were these files? Appdata?

Comment: They are, I'm guessing, either personal files (saves, screenshots), which will probably be located in Appdata, as TimmyJim points out, or they are download cache files which Steam downloaded to your main drive (C:) first. Cache can just be deleted (Steam might not even recognize the files upon redownloading the game, and, since the game still is being updated regularly, these files are likely dated anyway), but personal files, unless uploaded to the Steam cloud, could be wise to hold on to. Still, please let us know where the files are located.

Comment: They are in Program (x86)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam` (default Steam installation directory), as that contains the Steam program itself aside from the game files. If you delete it, you'll need to reinstall Steam along with your games installed on drive C if you want to play a Steam game.

Games files in drive C are installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\` by default, and it should be safe to delete them. However, it is better to use Steam's uninstaller instead: Library → Right-click the game → Manage → Uninstall, to also remove game files outside of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\`.

Comment: Steam _doesn't have to_ reside in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam` does it? You can choose where to install it during first setup correct?

Comment: @TimmyJim I think so, but OP said they found huge Cyberpunk 2077 files in `Program Files (x86)`, so I assumed that they must have used the default Steam installation directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam`.

Comment: @galacticninja No, it was some other files, like audio of night city and so on. I installed that game long after I was already using the second HDD for games.

Comment: @EndThusIAm To clarify, which files did you find, and in which directory? Are they under  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\`?